# Comparison of limits

Tags: analysis, limits

I would like to obtain the values of n for which the following is satisfied:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^n = \lim_{x\to 0} - (-x)^n$$

Upon observing I think it should be for all odd values of n. However the answer is for all values greater than 0. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} -(-x)^n=-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} (-x)^n=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} (-1)^nx^n=(-1)^n\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} x^n$

And the latter limit is $0$ for $n>0$.

Comment: But the two are limits which implies that they are never actually zero. Thus wouldn't they be equal at any odd value of n which cancels out the negative?